# How can I deactivate the Ctrl+M shortcut in the editor?

Tags: support, user-interface, citation, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

On my keyboard, I programmed <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> to be something special, and always when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> when I ask a question on Mathematics Stack Exchange, an "Insert Citation" appears! How can I deactivate this "Insert citation"? It's really annoying.

Answer (score 5):

[Rob W's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123256/214632) on Meta Stack Exchange contains a bookmarklet and a user script to disable **all** of the keyboard shortcuts in the editor.

The answer explains the methodology of the user script, but as is it will no longer work, since Stack Exchange uses `https` instead of `http`. You can fix this by changing all the `@match` lines to something like

```
// @match          *://stackoverflow.com/*
```

Also, MathOverflow is not part of the matched sites, so if you ever want to block the keyboard shortcuts on that site you'll have to add a line like

```
// @match          *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
```

to the preamble.

Someone better versed than I in user scripts could probably find a way to disable specific keyboard shortcuts.

---

For completeness, here's the user script with the minor changes described above.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Cya WMD shortcuts
// @namespace      Rob W
// @version        1.00001
// @match          *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match          *://*.superuser.com/*
// @match          *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match          *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match          *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match          *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match          *://stackapps.com/*
// @run-at         document-end
// @grant          none
// ==/UserScript==

(typeof unsafeWindow !== 'undefined' ? unsafeWindow : window).$(function() {
    var p = document.getElementById('wmd-input');
    if (!p) return;
    p = p.parentNode;
    function ignore(e){e.stopPropagation();}    
    p.addEventListener('keydown', ignore, true);
    p.addEventListener('keypress', ignore, true);
    p.addEventListener('keyup', ignore, true);
});
```

Comment: how can I get this file ?

Comment: You need to install an extension to your browser (_e.g._, [Tapermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/)), and then you can basically copy-and-paste the above code into the extension to get it to run.